# UiPath Add filter to all columns in Excel

Tags: ui-automation, rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, rda

I have a small problem. I have an excel file where I simply want to add a filter to all my columns. Firstly I don’t want to put a certain condition into the filter but just the option to filter with the toolbar with the small arrow.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Not sure what you want? More info and images needed.

Comment: The concern is that when you go to one cell and type ctrl+shift+L. That should create a filter on-top of the datatable within Excel. That is what I want to automate. I solved it by adding the click activity 3 times but I think that solution is not really elegant. Maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Send Hotkey activity to send "ctrl+Shift+L"
[image]